# How do I get data from tkinter and add it into turtle?

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle-graphics

I've been trying to tkinters .Entry command and use the user input to put into turtle, but I keep getting an error:

In my case, I am trying to ask the user for a color that they want to use in turtle.

My code:

```
import tkinter
from turtle import Turtle

#Create and Format window
w = tkinter.Tk()
w.title("Getting To Know You")
w.geometry("400x200")


#Favorite Color


lbl3= tkinter.Label(w, text = "What's your favorite color?")
lbl3.grid(row = 10 , column = 2)

olor = tkinter.Entry(w)
olor.grid(row = 12, column = 2)

t = Turtle()
t.begin_fill()
t.color(olor)
shape = int (input ("What is your favorite shape?"))

w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Entry is an Entry-object. to get a String from it, you net to run Entry.get() But I need more of your code to give a code as answer.

Comment: Okay, I can post my code if you would like

Comment: Please do so, or fix it yourself by using get(), so you see the difficulty: I can't know whats wrong

Comment: We don't need to see all your code. We need to see a [mcve]. You've posted a lot of code that is unrelated to the the problem being asked about.

Comment: So would something like this work ^^^^^

Comment: The current code will not create a problem.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The error I was getting was:

Comment: TypeError: object of type 'Entry' has no len()

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is you work within turtle completely and not drop down to the tkinter level:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

# Create and Format window
screen = Screen()
screen.setup(400, 200)
screen.title("Getting To Know You")

# Favorite Color

color = screen.textinput("Choose a color", "What's your favorite color?")

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.color(color)

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.circle(25)
turtle.end_fill()

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.mainloop()
```

If you must do this from tkinter, you need to read more about tkinter elements like `Entry` to know their capabilities.  You also need to read more about turtle as it is invoked differently when embedded inside of a tkinter window.  Here's a rough approximation of what you're trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from turtle import RawTurtle, TurtleScreen, ScrolledCanvas

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
root.title("Getting To Know You")

def draw_circle():
    turtle.color(color_entry.get())

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.circle(25)
    turtle.end_fill()

# Favorite Color

tk.Label(root, text="What's your favorite color?").pack()

color_entry = tk.Entry(root)
color_entry.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Draw Circle', command=draw_circle).pack()

canvas = ScrolledCanvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

screen = TurtleScreen(canvas)
turtle = RawTurtle(screen, visible=False)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I found this very useful.